# Laravel 5.4 Relationship hasMany not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, relationship

i have 2 model Article and ArtCategories

I made the one-to-many relation between two model using belongsTo() and hasMany(). hasMany() relation works perfectly but belongTo() doesn't work. Does anyone know where did I make a mistake?
.

Code model

```
class ArtCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pjt_categories_article';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cate_id';
    protected $fillable = ['cate_id','categories'];

    public function Article(){
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }
}
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pjt_article';
    protected $primaryKey = 'article_id';
    protected $fillable = ['article_id','title','descriptions','username','cate_id','status','visit','reference'];

    public function ArtCategories(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ArtCategories::class,'cate_id');
    }

    public function admin(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class);
    }
}
```

This is DB structure Table up is pjt_article ,table down is pjt_categories_article
[image]

Result

`$art = Article::findOrFail($article_id);
$cate = ArtCategories::pluck('categories', 'cate_id');
dd($art);`

[image]

Relation Not working

Comment: should be using [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) I guess. By default it doesn't load the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add foreign key in relation method of `ArtCategories`

```
class ArtCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pjt_categories_article';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cate_id';
    protected $fillable = ['cate_id','categories'];

    public function article(){
         return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'cate_id');
    }
}
```

Now fetch article with `ArtCategories` as:

```
$art = Article::with('ArtCategories')->findOrFail($article_id);
$cate = ArtCategories::pluck('categories', 'cate_id');
dd($art);
```

> As laravel convention `Article()` method should be `articles()` and `ArtCategories()` should be `artCategory()`.